# JSON not working from Google Finance

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to extract information from a JSON file from Google Finance.  The `requests.get()` is working but then I get stuck.  I have searched quite a bit and nothing suggested seems to work.  This is what I have:

```
import requests
from json import loads

params={'q': 'NASDAQ:AAPL','output': 'json'}
response = requests.get('https://finance.google.com/finance', params=params, allow_redirects=False, timeout=10.0)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)
```

The output is “200” which is the ok output I believe.  `print(response.content)` gives me the full JSON string so that seems to be working ok.

However, trying to pass it into “data” so that I can work with further, extract various bits. This is what I have tried:

- `data = response.json()` gives me `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)`
- `data = json.load(response)` gives me `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'`
- `data = json.loads(response)` gives me `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Response'`

I tried `data = json.loads(response.decode("utf-8"))` and that gives me `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'decode'`.  I have also tried some text scrubbing suggestions, nothing has worked yet.

Answer (score 1):

I printed the text. and I found that first some data is not json string...
\n // chars...

```
jsonstr = response.text[4:] #remove first part (not json data)
data = loads(jsonstr)
print(data)
print("t=",data[0]['t'])
```

output

```
[{'t': 'AAPL', 'kr_annual_date': '2017', 'hi': '180.52', 'keyratios': [{'title': 'Net profit margin', 'annual': '21.09%', 'recent_quarter': '25.67%', 'ttm': '22.21%'}, {'title': 'Operating margin', 'annual': '26.76%', 'rece ....
.... 
com/'}]}]
t= AAPL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `response.content` or `response.text` to convert to JSON.

**Ex:**

```
json.loads(response.content)
```

or

```
json.loads(response.text)
```